# Store script src in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am loading all assets and `js` & `css` from next page and store them in an `Array` but I forEach loop through the document and store the javascript link seperatly now so like this:

```
0:{images: Array(61)}
1:{js: script}
2:{js: script}
3:{js: script}
4:{js: script}
5:{js: script}
6:{js: script}
etc...
```

Here is the loop:

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll("script[src]"), function( src ) {
    console.log( src );
    resources.push({js: src})
 });
```

But how do I store them like the images all in one object instead of pushing them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You push `{js: []}` into `resources` **once**, and then push the scripts into the array that is the value of the `js` property.

(It doesn't make much sense to do this though, `resources` would probably be better off as an object with a `images` and a `js` property instead of as an array).

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
resources.push( {js : [ ...document.querySelectorAll( "script[src]" ) ] } );
```

Or better if you can set them as properties of `resource` (object instead of an *Array*) instead of

```
resource = {};
resources.js = [ ...document.querySelectorAll( "script[src]" ) ];
resources.images = [ ...document.querySelectorAll( "img" ) ];
```

For older browsers

```
var toArray = function( arrLike ){ return [].slice.call( arrLike ) };
resource = {};
resources.js = toArray( document.querySelectorAll( "script[src]" ) );
resources.images = toArray( document.querySelectorAll( "img" ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is the three dot notations executable in older browsers?